# C: Incompatible types?

Tags: c, types, struct, char

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo{
    int id;
    char *bar;
    char *baz[6];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct foo f;   
    f.id=1;

    char *qux[6];

    f.bar=argv[0];
    f.baz=qux;  // Marked line

    return 1;
}
```

This is just some test code so ignore that qux doesn't actually have anything useful in it.

I'm getting an error on the marked line, `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[6]’ from type ‘char **’` but both of the variables are defined as `char *[6]` in the code. Any insight?

Comment: `char *baz[6];` declares an array of 6 pointers. If you want to declare a pointer to an array, write `char (*baz)[6];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the line

```
f.baz=qux;
```

Tries to assign the array `qux` to the array `baz`.  In C, arrays are not variables and cannot be assigned new values.  To see a simpler example, this code:

```
int arr1[10], arr2[10];
arr1 = arr2; // Error!
```

Is illegal because the second line tries to assign the second array the value of the first, which is not allowed in C.

To fix this, you'll probably want to write an explicit loop to copy the elements over, as seen here:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    f.baz[i] = qux[i];
```

This is legal because each individual element of the array is a `char *`, which can be assigned.

You sometimes also see `memcpy` used to assign arrays:

```
memcpy(f.baz, qux, sizeof f.baz);
```

This copies over the raw bytes of all the fields in the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy arrays like that in C. You have to copy them element-by-element:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    f.baz[i] = qux[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you do assignments to physical memory directly. You can point to memory in 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits at the time. Array assignment needs to be done in equal pieces that match those possible portions that you can point to.

If there is need to point to multiple such arrays at different times you could do:

```
struct foo{
    char **baz;
};
```

That should allow you to change the array being pointed to as you did:

```
f.baz=qux;
```