# Incompatible types struct* and struct,

Tags: c, pointers, struct, incompatibletypeerror

Thanks for taking the time to read my question,
I've looked at a few similar questions and they don't seem to help in this instance
although may help others with similar troubles:

[C: Incompatible types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164496/c-incompatible-types)
   [Struct as incompatible pointer type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203047/struct-as-incompatible-pointer-type-in-c)
   [Incompatible Types Error with Struct C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869755/incompatible-types-error-with-struct-c)

I'm attempting to create a simple linked list structure in c (-std=c99),
my structure is fairly generic at this point:

```
typedef struct
{
  int count;
  char* word;
  struct node *nextNode;
}node;
```

then in a function i have a "root" or "head" node:

```
node *root;
root = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

and i attempt to assign a `node` to the root nodes `nextNode` later on in the function like so:

```
if(root->nextNode == 0)
{
  root->nextNode = foo;
}
```

Which leads to an error:
    "error incompatibles types when assigning to type `struct node*` from type `node`
    `&foo` does not improve the situation, instead resulting in a `lvalue required as unary` style error.

Here is the context surrounding my issue:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        int count;
        char* word;
        struct node *nextNode;
    }node;

    node makenode(char *word)
    {
        node x;
        x.word = word;
        x.count = 1;
        return x;
    }

    void processInput(int threshold, const char* filename)
    {   
        node *root;
        root = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
        root->nextNode = 0;  
        char* word;
        while(fgets(word, 29, stdin) != NULL){
            if(root->nextNode == 0)
            {
                root->nextNode = makenode(word);
            }
```

Comment: Error message seems clear. x* ("a pointer to x") and x are different types.

Comment: You are certainly correct, however i'm unsure how to fix this dispite how simple it must seem.

Comment: How is variable 'foo' defined as.  Type of root->nextNode is pointer to "struct node" as defined. What is type of foo?  Is foo defind like "node *foo"?   You should show the part of code which contains definition of foo.

Comment: node foo;
 foo.word = word_val;
 foo.count = 1;

Comment: You cannot assign a `node` to a `node *`. Post more of your code relating to construction of `foo` (directly in the question, not in the comments). You will almost certainly need to construct `foo` dynamically (via `malloc`) for this to work.

Comment: You are doing `node *root;root = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));` but **not** `node *foo;foo = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));`. You need to explain the difference to yourself first, then to us.

Comment: So when you added the reference operator (&) whAt did you use it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem

```
    typedef struct             // make an alias for a structure with no tag name
    {
        int count;
        char* word;
        struct node *nextNode; // with a pointer to struct node (which does not exit)
    }node;                     // name the alias node
```

Solution

```
    typedef struct node        // make an alias for a structure with tag name node
    {
        int count;
        char* word;
        struct node *nextNode; // with a pointer to struct node (which is this one)
    }node;                     // name the alias node
```

Comment: This was probably going to cause me issues down the road but didn't help at this point.

Comment: After applying this and using *root->nextNode it seems to be functioning fine. I'm not entirely comfortable with why i need a *, but it works. thank you.

Comment: @user16249: the latest code in your question now exposes more errors and doesn't match what you said in this comment. Can you update your question to reflect the latest changes you have made, so we can explain the remaining issues?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct node //should give a name for this 
    {
        int count;
        char* word;
        struct node *nextNode;
    }node;

    static node *makenode(char *word) //start with static and returning type is node* because we are storing this output in root->nextNode which is *node pointer
    {
        node x;
        x.word = word;
        x.count = 1;
        return x;
    }

    void processInput(int threshold, const char* filename)
    {   
        node *root;
        root = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
        root->nextNode = NULL;  //pointer values should initialised to NULL not 0
        char* word;
        while(fgets(word, 29, stdin) != NULL){
            if(root->nextNode == NULL) ////pointer values should initialised to NULL not 0
            {
                root->nextNode = makenode(word);
            }
}
```